# Jquery select2 keeps reopening after selecting value

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

So I'm working with a select2 combobox, and it appears fine, but whenever I click on a value it closes but reopens instantly, and it's impossible to select a value and close it.
I've tried turning on and off autoclose. I've also tried adding an onChange function to force close but reopens again. The plugin is default I just have this changes in my code

```
$(".select-2-single, .select-2-single-2").select2({
                    multiple: false,
                    closeOnSelect: true
                });
```

Other than that, nothing is changed, it just never closes.

EDIT:

Found a solution. Just destroyed and initialized again, it won't lose the value selected and it's invisible to the naked eye.

```
var $example = $(".select-2-single-2").select2();
            $example.select2("destroy");
            $example.select2();
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is correct as per [Select2](https://select2.org/dropdown#forcing-the-dropdown-to-remain-open-after-selection).

```
$(".select-2-single, .select-2-single-2")
```

You are using two classes here. Check if both of classes being used by same select.
Or Try to call separate for both classes.

```
$(".select-2-single").select2({
     multiple: false,
     closeOnSelect: true
});

$(".select-2-single-2").select2({
     multiple: false,
     closeOnSelect: true
});
```

Comment: Separating them both does nothing. Both of them are rightly declared and each one has its own class

Comment: See this [link](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4939). Hope this helps.Also check console if there is any error.

Comment: Already seen that. The problem it's not that it's not closing, is that it reopens for some reason. Will look into console, but I'm pretty sure there are no errors.